# Necesito que me ayuden a resolver este ejercicio de arreglos en java

Tags: java, array, arraylist, java-util-scanner

[image]

Este es el problema que tengo, lo que está entre paréntesis todos son i, es decir s(i), a(i), b(i), d(i), c(i), necesito que me ayuden por favor es para un trabajo final y el profesor no explicó bien.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     int i=0;
     
     int a[] = new int[2];
     int b[] = new int[2];
     int[] S = new int[a[i] + b[i]];
     
     for(i=0; i<= a.length; i++){
         System.out.print("A["+(i+1)+"]: ");
         a[i]= entrada.nextInt();
         System.out.print("b["+(i+1)+"]: ");
         b[i]= entrada.nextInt();
       
     } 
     for(i=0; i<= a.length; i++){
         System.out.print("b["+(i+1)+"]: ");
         b[i]= entrada.nextInt();
       
     } 
        
        
         if (a[i]%2==0 && b[i]%2==0){
           int D[] = new int[a[i]- b[i]];  
         }
         
        System.out.println(S[i]); 
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que he probado pero no me sale nada bien, básicamente lo que quiero es resolver el problema de la foto de arriba, pero no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto y la verdad mi profesor no nos explico muy bien.

Comment: Saludos. Falta el código de lo que has intentado; así mismo los datos que proporcionas, el resultado que obtienes si lo que obtienes es error proporcionarlo o si es resultado erroneo poner cual es el esperado. Así te podrán guiar para que lo logres.

Comment: Ok gracias bro.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Básicamente necesitas 5 array del mismo tipo de dato y longitud (para almacenar misma cantidad de elementos). Una vez que tengas lleno `A` y `B` (empieza con datos fijos para que sepas anticipadamente tus resultados), con un ciclo `for` llenar cada posición de `S`,  `D` y `C` con la operación respectiva. Desde luego, al final será ideal muestres los contenidos de los 5 arreglos para corroborar.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar que problema estas teniendo? El código tiene algunos errores, pero no especificas que quieres solucionar.

Answer (score 1):

Según he entendido, debes de tener 2 `arrays` con una longitud de 20, e introducir diferentes números.

Después en otros 3 diferentes `arrays` tienes que guardar diferentes cálculos en base a los 2 anteriores `array`.

En primer lugar, creamos 5 diferentes `arrays`:

```
    // Arrays
    int[] a = new int [20];
    int[] b = new int [20];
    
    int[] s = new int [20];
    int[] d = new int [20];
    int[] c = new int [20];
```

Después, con una variable que almacena números aleatorios (para no introducirlos manualmente, y agregar en cada ejecución nuevos números) se lo vamos añadiendo a **A y a B**:

```
    // Introducir numeros dentro del array A y B
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() *50 + 1);
        a[i] = aleatorio;
        
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() *50 + 1);
        b[i] = aleatorio;   
    }
```

Ahora ya tenemos la base del ejercicio: Tener 2 `arrays` llenos de diferentes números.

Y ahora nos pide que **dentro de S**, guardemos en cada iteración la suma de A en pocisión `i` y B en 1:

```
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        
        s[i] = a[i] + b[1]; 
    }
```

**Con D** nos pide que si `i` es **par** guardemos la resta de A en posición 1 y B en 1, y en caso de ser **impar**, lo multipliquemos y **lo almacenemos en C**:

```
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        
        if(i%2 != 0) { // IMPAR
            c[i] = a[1] * b[1];
        }else {
            d[i] = a[1] - b[1];
        }
    }
```

Con esto el ejercicio está listo, solo debes de mostrar los elementos. Lo he realizado de esta forma para que sea vea "elegante":

```
    for(int i=0; i<d.length;i++) {
        
        if(d[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println("D[" + i +"]: " + d[i]);
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++) {
        
        if(c[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println("C[" + i +"]: " + c[i]);
        }   
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<s.length;i++) {
        
        System.out.println("S[" + (i+1) +"]: " + s[i]);
    }
```

**NOTA:** Para mostrar, he utilizado diferentes `for`, por que no sabemos a ciencia cierta que longitud tendrá el `array` **D** y **C**. Y al ser un `array` con longitud de 20, habrá posiciones que serán un 0, por eso antes de imprimir verifico que no sea un 0.

**CÓDIGO COMPLETO:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arreglos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Arrays
        int[] a = new int [20];
        int[] b = new int [20];
        
        int[] s = new int [20];
        int[] d = new int [20];
        int[] c = new int [20];
                
        // Escaner y numero aleatorio   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int aleatorio;
            
        // Introducir numeros dentro del array A y B
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            
            aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() *50 + 1);
            a[i] = aleatorio;
            
            aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() *50 + 1);
            b[i] = aleatorio;
            
        }
            
        // Introducir los datos en los demas Array
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            
            s[i] = a[i] + b[1]; 
        }
            
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            
            if(i%2 != 0) { // IMPAR
                c[i] = a[1] * b[1];
            }else {
                d[i] = a[1] - b[1];
            }
        }
        
        // Mostar arrays:
        for(int i=0; i<d.length;i++) {
            
            if(d[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println("D[" + i +"]: " + d[i]);
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++) {
            
            if(c[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println("C[" + i +"]: " + c[i]);
            }   
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<s.length;i++) {
            
            System.out.println("S[" + (i+1) +"]: " + s[i]);
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: El código puede ser refactorizado, puedes ponerte como reto simplificarlo un poco mas. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos, no sabe de la que me salvaron

Comment: @JohanSemprum si te sirvió la respuesta, acéptala :)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo en tu enunciado, debes leer dos arrays de 20 posiciones cada uno. En mi solución indico los números directamente en la inicialización.

A continuación, defino los tres arrays necesarios:
S de 20 posiciones ya que almacenará todas las sumas.
D de 10 posiciones ya que almacenará sólo las pares.
C de 10 posiciones ya que almacenará sólo las impares.

Siguiendo, realizamos las operaciones, atento al i/2 que es para direccionar correctamente la casilla de los arrays D y C.

Por último, defino un módulo que dado un vector, lo muestra por pantalla.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Aqui deberias leerlo por teclado en vez de inicializar como yo hago.
    int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    int B[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

    int S[] = new int[20];
    int D[] = new int[10];
    int C[] = new int[10];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        S[i] = A[i] + B[i];
        if(i%2==0) {
            D[i/2]=A[i]-B[i];
        }
        else {
            C[i/2]=A[i]*B[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Mostrando arreglo S:");
    mostrar(S);
    System.out.println("Mostrando arreglo D:");
    mostrar(D);
    System.out.println("Mostrando arreglo C:");
    mostrar(C);
    
}

private static void mostrar(int[] s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(s[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Espero que te sirva.